# SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException -> Column "name" can not be null INTRESTING

Tags: sql, spring, hibernate

So, i create Entity in my DB from CommandLineRunner, everything okay.
Then i create some controller one of them give me next Exception, when i going to update my Entity ->

```
***java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'name' cannot be null***
```

**Controller**

```
@PostMapping ("/update")
    public String update (Instructor instructor) {
        instructorService.updateInstructor(instructor);
        return "redirect:/instructors/index";
    }
```

**Entity**

```
@Entity
@Table (name = "Instructor")
public class Instructor {
    
    @Id
        @GeneratedValue (strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        @Column (name = "instructor_id", nullable = false)
        private Long instructorId;
        
        @Basic
        @Column (name = "name", nullable = false, length = 45)
        private String firstName;
        
        @Basic  
        @Column (name = "lastName", nullable = false, length = 45)
        private String lastName;
        
        @Basic
        @Column (name = "summary", nullable = false, length = 45)
        private String instructorSummary;
        
        @OneToMany (mappedBy = "instructor", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        private Set <Course> courses = new HashSet<>();
        
        @OneToOne (cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
        @JoinColumn (name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "user_id", nullable = false)
        private User user;
```

When i delete (nullable=false) everything work by Entity does not appear in DB

**Instructor Service**

```
Instructor updateInstructor (Instructor instructor);
```

**InstructorImpl**

```
@Override
    public Instructor updateInstructor(Instructor instructor) {
        return instructorDao.save(instructor);
    }
```

DaoClass only extend JpaRepository

Update: here are the logs

> Hibernate: update instructor set name=?, summary=?, last_name=?,
> user_id=? where instructor_id=? 2023-01-13T14:41:40.545+02:00 WARN
> 4176 --- [nio-8071-exec-2] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper :
> SQL Error: 1048, SQLState: 23000 2023-01-13T14:41:40.545+02:00 ERROR
> 4176 --- [nio-8071-exec-2] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper :
> Column 'name' cannot be null 2023-01-13T14:41:40.551+02:00 ERROR 4176
> --- [nio-8071-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet] : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path
> [] threw exception [Request processing failed:
> org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not
> execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [null]] with root cause

Comment: Can you provide an example post request you are using that causes the error? I noticed your column name is "name" but the field name is "firstName" so I suspect deserialization issue with the data you are feeding the endpoint.

Comment: please help me with that, i send Hibernate log when i click on Button update

Comment: How do you send request? Add json request code

Comment: i use HTML + Thymeleaf

Comment: Open your HTML page in Chrome or Edge. Right-click in the page and click "Inspect". Then dev tools will show. Click on the "Network" tab.  Now, click the Update button on your HTML page, and look for the request in the Network tab. Right-click the request and go to "Copy->Copy as cURL (bash)". Then paste inside this question, but remove any private information you see like domain and or cookies. We are mostly interested in the JSON data that is sent. Alternatively, if you click on the request and go to "Payload" tab, you can copy and send that here.